# How to report a bug to the installer?

Tags: 14.04, server, 14.10, raid, busybox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server on an old Mac workstation with EFI firmware, and I'm trying to use software raid for the root partition. The installation aborts during package installation(maybe configuration), complaining about busybox-initrd. This happens both on server 14.04.1 and on server 14.10. How can I report this bug?

Comment: Try `ubuntu-bug ubiquity`

Comment: I don't use ubuntu. As I can't install it, I can't run this.

Comment: Did you eliminate other possibilities? Made a new bootable disk with different software, for example? or different media?

Comment: I'm not asking for help to solve the issue, I'm asking help to report a bug.

Comment: the install media is ok. The installation aborts during the package installation, more specifically on installation or configuration of busybox-initrd

Comment: Oh, ok. The most common mention of busybox here is the notorious  prompt during failed boots. I confused your problem with that. but if you can run the installer, you can also run `ubuntu-bug` from the live environment. If you're on a server edition, the installation program is probably provided by the [`debian-installer`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=debian-installer) package.

Comment: IIRC You can press Ctrl-Alt-F2/F3/F4 to get to a TTY on the server edition installer, and from there you can run `apport-cli` as mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Filing_bugs_when_offline_or_using_a_headless_setup).

Answer (score -2):

I found this link should help :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Is there anything about the installer there?

Comment: I'm not to sure you will have to give it a read but if not you could always attempt to contact the team.

Comment: That link was my starting point. I'm following the instructions of asking support. See step 2.

Comment: The IRC is probably your best bet

Comment: Druid, thank you for working to help out users in the Ubuntu Q&A site. There is a shortage of people to help out. Please read [You answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) to understand why users in SE do not like answers that are only links.